Check if string contains a substring representing date and hour in various formats
I have a bunch of pictures in a folder, pictures whose names contain a substring which represent a date(time) like "YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS", "YYYYMMDD" or "YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS" and I would like to get the corresponding DateTime. I know how to do it (with several TryParseExact) would the name be exactly of these forms but it's the substring part which bothers me has I don't know how to code that. (I never used regexes so far.)

By the way TryParseExact also takes an array of formats to try at once.

Another approach using regular expression.
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

        string regexPattern = @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{8}_\d{6}|\d{8}";

        foreach (string filePath in fileNames)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
            Match match = Regex.Match(fileName, regexPattern);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                string dateString = match.Value;
                DateTime dateTime;

                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, 
                    new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", "yyyyMMdd" }, 
                    null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"File: {fileName}, DateTime: {dateTime}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"File: {fileName}, Could not parse date");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"File: {fileName}, No valid date found");
            }
        }
    }
}


You could run 3 regexes, one for each format.
Something like this
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testData = new string[]
        {
            "testfile2004-12-30-13-55-23.png",
            "2004-12-30-13-55-23testfile.png",
            "testfile20041230.png",
            "20041230testfile.png",
            "testfile20041230_135523.png",
            "20041230_135523testfile.png",
        };

        foreach (var fileName in testData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTimeFromFileName(fileName));
        }
    }
    //
    private static DateTime DateTimeFromFileName(string fileName)
    {
        var dateTimePatterns = new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", "yyyyMMdd", "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" };

        foreach (var pattern in dateTimePatterns)
        {
            var regex = "";
            switch (pattern)
            {
                case "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss":
                    regex = @"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}";
                    break;
                case "yyyyMMdd":
                    regex = @"\d{8}";
                    break;
                case "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss":
                    regex = @"\d{8}_\d{6}";
                    break;
                
            }
            var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(fileName, regex);
            if (match.Success && DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Value, pattern, null,
                    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out var dateTime))
                return dateTime;
        }
        throw new FormatException("No valid date-time format found in the file name.");
    }
}

